# How to combine result sets from batch queries?

Tags: javascript, php, quickbooks

The quickbooks API only returns 1000 items for any SQL query, so I need to query in batches.  My question is, how can I add the results together in php?

```
$customers = [];
$start_position = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number_of_queries; $i++) {
    $customers[$i] = $customer_service->query(
        $this->qb->context,
        $this->qb->realm,
        "SELECT * FROM Customer STARTPOSITION " . $start_position . " MAXRESULTS 1000"
    );
    $start_position += 1000;
}

return json_encode($customers);
```

Question: How can I combine `$customers[1]`, `$customers[2]`, `$customers[3]`, etc. into one array containing all customer data?

Or, if it would be better to do this client side, how can this be done in JavaScript?

I've looked into [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [array operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) but these solutions overwrite if the keys are the same, which they are.

Also, I've looked into [concat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) in JavaScript.  However, I'm not able to get this to work.

Does anyone have any experience with combining result sets from batch queries?

[image: Screen Shot of Console]

Comment: What do the keys look like?

Comment: The result of the query is an array of customers.  Each customer expands to an object of key `*_data` which contains all customer data (several different keys).

Comment: Is it an array of anonymous objects that make up a customer? Like `[{...}, {...}, {...}]` in the JSON? Or is it more like `{customer_1: {..}, customer_2: {...}}`. In short, maybe paste an example of one of the values that is going to be in `$customers` arary. I think we need more details on the structure to suggest how to merge the result sets.

Comment: @Cymen, I'm having trouble writing the contents to a file.  I took a screenshot of the console instead.  Note that the array is only 177 customers long in this case but I am also able to test the code with a 9000+ customer result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using PHP's `array_merge()` function.

```
$customers = [];
$start_position = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number_of_queries; $i++) {
    $results = $customer_service->query(
        $this->qb->context,
        $this->qb->realm,
        "SELECT * FROM Customer STARTPOSITION " . $start_position . " MAXRESULTS 1000"
    );
    $start_position += 1000;
    $customers = array_merge($customers, results);
}

return json_encode($customers);
```

Comment: Well, I'll be damned.

Comment: Glad to be of service!